# Fill in rows in Pandas by date, conditional on row not existing

Tags: python, pandas

How can you 'copy' previous rows from a Pandas dataframe where it is indexed by a date, if the row does not exist on the next date. This is motivated by the problem below.

**Problem**

My example `data` is

```
DATE | TEAM | PLAYER
-----+------+-------
 0   |  A   |  John
 0   |  A   |  Tom
 0   |  B   |  Chris
 0   |  B   |  Rob
 1   |  A   |  John
 1   |  A   |  George
 1   |  B   |  Chris
 2   |  A   |  Rob
```

I am trying to build on object `X` so that I can do something like

```
X.loc[date, team]
```

and it will return all `players` whose last observation was for `team` on `date`.

Now to be clear, I would want

```
X.loc[0, 'A'] = ['John', 'Tom']
X.loc[0, 'B'] = ['Chris', 'Rob']

X.loc[1, 'A'] = ['John', 'Tom', 'George']
X.loc[1, 'B'] = ['Chris', 'Rob']

X.loc[2, 'A'] = ['John', 'Tom', 'George', 'Rob']
X.loc[2, 'B'] = ['Chris']
```

**Idea**

My idea was that I could 'fill in' values from previous dates for players who were not observed on that date e.g. `data_filled`

```
DATE | TEAM | PLAYER | FILLED
-----+------+--------+-------
 0   |  A   |  John  |   0
 0   |  A   |  Tom   |   0
 0   |  B   |  Chris |   0
 0   |  B   |  Rob   |   0
 1   |  A   |  John  |   0
 1   |  A   |  George|   0
 1   |  B   |  Chris |   0
 1   |  A   |  Tom   |   1
 1   |  B   |  Rob   |   1
 2   |  A   |  Rob   |   0
 2   |  A   |  John  |   1
 2   |  A   |  George|   1
 2   |  B   |  Chris |   1
 2   |  A   |  Tom   |   1
```

where I added a `FILLED` column just to represent if the row was added to `data`. Now I believe I can get what I want by

```
X = data_filled.set_index(['DATE', 'TEAM'])
```

and I can the use

```
X.loc[data, team]
```

to get the list of players.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: `X.loc[1, 'B'] = ['Chris', 'Rob']; X.loc[1, 'B'] = ['Chris']`. Do you want Rob or not?

Comment: That's a typo the bottom two should have date of 2. Not sure if I can edit on phone but will when back at computer.

Comment: shouldn't [2, B] have Chris & Rob?

Comment: No, the point is `Rob` moves over to team `A` as this is the last team we saw him play for.

Answer (score 1):

> return all players whose last observation was for team on date.

rather than constructing a dataframe to use `DataFrame.loc`, you can define a custom `loc` function

Given a date `n`, we can get the last team for all the players using:

```
last_team = df[df.DATE<=n].groupby('PLAYER').TEAM.agg('last')
```

Then we can select the players in a given team

```
last_team.index[last_team.TEAM=='A'].values
```

Combine the two steps above in a function call as you need.

```
def myloc(frame, date, team):
    last_team = frame[frame['DATE']<=date].groupby('PLAYER')['TEAM'].agg('last')
    return last_team.index[last_team == team].values
```

Example outputs:

```
In [11]: myloc(df, 0, 'A')
Out[10]: array(['John', 'Tom'], dtype=object)

In [11]: myloc(df, 1, 'A')
Out[11]: array(['George', 'John', 'Tom'], dtype=object)

In [12]: myloc(df, 2, 'A')
Out[12]: array(['George', 'John', 'Rob', 'Tom'], dtype=object)

In [13]: myloc(df, 0, 'B')
Out[13]: array(['Chris', 'Rob'], dtype=object)

In [14]: myloc(df, 1, 'B')
Out[14]: array(['Chris', 'Rob'], dtype=object)

In [15]: myloc(df, 2, 'B')
Out[15]: array(['Chris'], dtype=object)
```

A higher performing approach would be to use pd.merge_asof to construct a table of players and their most recent team membership on a given date.

First, we have to build a table of all possible players & dates.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.DATE.unique(), df.PLAYER.unique()])).reset_index()
df2.columns = ['DATE', 'PLAYER']
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df, on='DATE', by='PLAYER').set_index(['DATE', 'TEAM']).sort_index()

df3
# outputs
           PLAYER
DATE TEAM
0    A       John
     A        Tom
     B      Chris
     B        Rob
     NaN   George
1    A       John
     A        Tom
     A     George
     B      Chris
     B        Rob
2    A       John
     A        Tom
     A        Rob
     A     George
     B      Chris
```

Then you can use `loc` to get the players who were last observed playing for a team

```
df3.loc[0, 'A'].PLAYER.values
# outputs: array(['John', 'Tom'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I like this, I wonder what the performance difference would be using this versus constructing the new dataframe.

Comment: this is definitely less performant than constructing a data frame 1 and just looking up the value. how big is your data frame likely to get?

Answer (score 1):

This approach forward-fills each player's last known team into future dates. I create intermediate variables to avoid a huge one-liner.

```
ffilled = df.set_index(['PLAYER', 'DATE']).unstack().ffill(axis=1)
tidy = ffilled.stack().reset_index()
result = tidy.set_index(['DATE', 'TEAM']).sort_index()

result
               PLAYER
DATE TEAM        
0    A       John
     A        Tom
     B      Chris
     B        Rob
1    A     George
     A       John
     A        Tom
     B      Chris
     B        Rob
2    A     George
     A       John
     A        Rob
     A        Tom
     B      Chris

result.loc[1, 'A']
           PLAYER
DATE TEAM        
1    A     George
     A       John
     A        Tom

result.loc[1, 'A'].values.flatten().tolist()
['George', 'John', 'Tom']
```